# How to draw/render different shapes in DirectX 11

Tags: c++, directx-11

I have been trying to learn the basics of DirectX 11 programming using the MSDN tutorial05 sample code and I have run into an issue I cannot find a solution for on the internet (that I could see anyway). Basically I am trying to draw and render a player cube object, complete with user input, and pyramid-like objects that the player must collect.

My issue is that when I am rendering the scene, only the cube vertex (and indices) data is being read so all objects are cubes when they shouldn't be.

This is the function where the vertex data is made:

```
PyramidVertex Pyramid[] =
{
    // Square base of the pyramid
    { XMFLOAT3( -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
    { XMFLOAT3( 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) },
    { XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
    { XMFLOAT3(0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f) },

    // The tip of the pyramid
    { XMFLOAT3(0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f), XMFLOAT4(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f) },
};
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bdP;
ZeroMemory(&bdP, sizeof(bdP));
bdP.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bdP.ByteWidth = sizeof(PyramidVertex) * 5;
bdP.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bdP.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitPData;
ZeroMemory(&InitPData, sizeof(InitPData));
InitPData.pSysMem = Pyramid;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bdP, &InitPData, &g_pVertexBufferP);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;  

// Set vertex buffer
UINT pStride = sizeof(PyramidVertex);
UINT pOffset = 1;
g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &g_pVertexBufferP, &pStride, &pOffset);

// create the index buffer 
DWORD pIndex[] =
{
    0, 2, 1,    
    1, 2, 3,
    0, 1, 4,    
    1, 3, 4,
    3, 2, 4,
    2, 0, 4,
};

// create the index buffer
bdP.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
bdP.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD) * 18;
bdP.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
bdP.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
bdP.MiscFlags = 0;
InitPData.pSysMem = pIndex;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bdP, &InitPData, &g_pIndexBufferP);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;

// Set index buffer
g_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(g_pIndexBufferP, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);

// Set primitive topology
g_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);


// Create vertex buffer
SimpleVertex vertices[] =
{
    { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f ), XMFLOAT4(  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT4(  .0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ), XMFLOAT4 (1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT4(  0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
    { XMFLOAT3( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ), XMFLOAT4( .0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ) },
};
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bd;
ZeroMemory( &bd, sizeof(bd) );
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( SimpleVertex ) * 8;
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
ZeroMemory( &InitData, sizeof(InitData) );
InitData.pSysMem = vertices;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pVertexBuffer );
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;

// Set vertex buffer
UINT stride = sizeof( SimpleVertex );
UINT offset = 0;
g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset );

// Create index buffer
WORD indices[] =
{
    3,1,0,
    2,1,3,

    0,5,4,
    1,5,0,

    3,4,7,
    0,4,3,

    1,6,5,
    2,6,1,

    2,7,6,
    3,7,2,

    6,4,5,
    7,4,6,
};
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof( WORD ) * 36;        // 36 vertices needed for 12 triangles in a triangle list
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
InitData.pSysMem = indices;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, &InitData, &g_pIndexBuffer );
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;

// Set index buffer
g_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer( g_pIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0 );

// Set primitive topology
g_pImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);


// Create the constant buffer
bd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bd.ByteWidth = sizeof(ConstantBuffer);
bd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
bd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer( &bd, nullptr, &g_pConstantBuffer );
if( FAILED( hr ) )
    return hr;

// Create the constant buffer
bdP.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bdP.ByteWidth = sizeof(ConstantBuffer);
bdP.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
bdP.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
hr = g_pd3dDevice->CreateBuffer(&bdP, nullptr, &g_pConstantBufferP);
if (FAILED(hr))
    return hr;

// Initialize the world matrix
g_Player = XMMatrixIdentity();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    g_Shapes[i] = XMMatrixIdentity();
}

// Initialize the view matrix
XMVECTOR Eye = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f );
XMVECTOR At = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
XMVECTOR Up = XMVectorSet( 0.0f, 4.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
g_View = XMMatrixLookAtLH( Eye, At, Up );

// Initialize the projection matrix
g_Projection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH( XM_PIDIV2, width / (FLOAT)height, 0.01f, 100.0f );
```

I believe that the issue is somewhere here and my theory is that the pyramid g_pImmediateContext is being overwritten when it comes to drawing the cubes. If this is the case then I have no clue on how to solve, or research, this problem. I has taken me an hour to figure out to put my code on this page properly but got weird results so I will leave a link to my [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3lBEhssq4ajMHBwdldlWGFFcms/view?usp=sharing) containing this code if someone wants to have an in-depth look (for whatever reason) at the code.

This is the render function:

```
//
// Clear the back buffer
//
g_pImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView(g_pRenderTargetView, Colors::Black);

//
// Clear the depth buffer to 1.0 (max depth)
//
g_pImmediateContext->ClearDepthStencilView(g_pDepthStencilView, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH, 1.0f, 0);

XMMATRIX mRotate = XMMatrixRotationZ(DXGame->playerUser->getRotation());
XMMATRIX mTranslate = XMMatrixTranslation(DXGame->playerUser->getXpos(), DXGame->playerUser->getYpos(), DXGame->playerUser->getZpos());
XMMATRIX mScale = XMMatrixScaling(0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f);
g_Player = mScale * mRotate * mTranslate;

ConstantBuffer cb1;
cb1.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose(g_Player);
cb1.mView = XMMatrixTranspose(g_View);
cb1.mProjection = XMMatrixTranspose(g_Projection);
g_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(g_pConstantBuffer, 0, nullptr, &cb1, 0, 0);

g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader(g_pVertexShader, nullptr, 0);
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &g_pConstantBuffer);
g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(g_pPixelShader, nullptr, 0);
g_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{   
    XMMATRIX sRotate = XMMatrixRotationY((DXGame->pickUps[i].rotation += 0.001f));
    XMMATRIX sTranslate = XMMatrixTranslation(DXGame->pickUps[i].xPos, DXGame->pickUps[i].yPos, DXGame->pickUps[i].zPos);
    XMMATRIX sScale = XMMatrixScaling(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f);

    g_Shapes[i] = sScale * sRotate * sTranslate;        

    ConstantBuffer constB;
    constB.mWorld = XMMatrixTranspose(g_Shapes[i]);
    constB.mView = XMMatrixTranspose(g_View);
    constB.mProjection = XMMatrixTranspose(g_Projection);
    g_pImmediateContext->UpdateSubresource(g_pConstantBufferP, 0, nullptr, &constB, 0, 0);

    g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader(g_pVertexShader, nullptr, 0);
    g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &g_pConstantBufferP);
    g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(g_pPixelShader, nullptr, 0);
    g_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(18, 0, 0);
}

g_pSwapChain->Present(0, 0);
```

Something I am also looking at is constant buffers and HLSL to see if that is an issue as well.

Please could someone at least point me in the right direction as this issue has bugged me for almost 2 months now (I left it this long because I wanted to figure it out for myself but now I am desperate for a solution).

Thank you for taking the time to read this post, sorry its so long but I needed to get as much info out there as possible in the hope that it is easier to read.

Comment: First of all use Visual Studio's graphics debugger to check the contents of pixel shader. This code has dependencies with vertex and fragment shaders too so you will have to post them too. But before doing so let us know if you can see anything via graphics debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your calls to IASetIndexBuffer and IASetVertexBuffers are in your creation routines, They need to be in your render function (before to call the relevant Draw function, as those are attaching those buffers to the runtime before drawing)

They do not need to be in creation part at all (as in DirectX11 context eg building commands and device eg : creating resource are decoupled).

You should have, in the render loop:

```
// Set vertex buffer and index buffer for your cube
UINT stride = sizeof( SimpleVertex );
UINT offset = 0;
g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, 
 &offset );

// Set index buffer
g_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer( g_pIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 
0 );

g_pImmediateContext->VSSetShader(g_pVertexShader, nullptr, 0);
g_pImmediateContext->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &g_pConstantBuffer);
g_pImmediateContext->PSSetShader(g_pPixelShader, nullptr, 0);
g_pImmediateContext->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);
```

and just before to draw all pyramids:

```
// Set vertex buffer and index buffer for pyramids as you will draw it 10 times, you can do it once just before the loop as geometry will not change
UINT stride = sizeof( SimpleVertex );
UINT offset = 0;
g_pImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers( 0, 1, &g_pVertexBuffer, &stride, 
&offset );
// Set index buffer
 g_pImmediateContext->IASetIndexBuffer(g_pIndexBufferP, DXGI_FORMAT_R16_UINT, 0);


for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{ 
    //Same draw code as before 
}
```

Comment: This worked! I can't thank you enough for your help!